ESP32 Boot Mode
I am using ESP32-S3-WROOM-1-N16R2 in my design. In ESP32-S3 development board schematic they connect boot pin GPIO0 with external switch.
The reference image of dev board link is below:
https://dl.espressif.com/dl/schematics/SCH_ESP32-S3-DevKitC-1_V1.1_20221130.pdf
But in my design I don't want boot switch. But I want give provision for that boot pin like pull down or pullup. Initially I connect the boot pin to the external 2-pin header. But now I need to connect that boot pin either pullup or pulldown. In my project ESP32 programmed for deep sleep mode. Please guide me for this.

what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post
